# How to find a triple of keys that maps plaintext to given cipherext using EDE

Tags: encryption, keys

What is a practical method for for finding a triple of keys that maps a given plaintext to a given ciphertext using EDE?

I think this requires something similar to a man-in-the-middle attack...

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Your question in the title is off-topic here though it is about Cryptography. What is the practical method? What is the name of the encryption algorithm?

Comment: @fgrieu This sounds awfully much like an answer, fgrieu. I've removed "implement" from the title, I presume that "find" was implied. It can always be reverted, but note questions asking for code are considered off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, that's a case for [Meet-in-the-Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack).

Notice that $E_{K_3}(D_{K_2}(E_{K_1}(P)))=C$ if and only if $D_{K_2}(E_{K_1}(P))=D_{K_3}(C)$. Therefore, finding $(K_1,K_2)$ and $K_3$ making the two sides equal solves the problem. Both sides take random-like values when $(K_1,K_2)$ and $K_3$ vary. Therefore trying $2^{b/2}$ values (e.g. incremental) of $(K_1,K_2)$ and $K_3$ leads to collision with fair probability (where $b$ is the block size in bits).

For an actual implementation with $b=64$ (as in DES), I would

- fix an arbitrary $K_1$ and compute $Q=E_{K_1}(P)$
- tabulate values of $D_{K_2}(Q)$ for incremental values of $K_2$ in a data structure allowing fast access given the result and recovery of $K_2$. Well over $2^{31}$ values of $D_{K_2}(Q)$ fit in my computer's available memory of 30 GB.
- compute $D_{K_3}(C)$ for incremental $K_3$ until getting a match.

Success is expected with about $3\cdot 2^{32}$ DES operations, which is very feasible.

Note: in the above, *incremental* must deal with the fact that the low-order bits of DES key bytes is ignored, [so as to](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34228/555) lower DES's resistance against brute force attack.

That has cost $\mathcal O(2^{b/2})$ effort and memory. The memory, but not the effort, can be reduced a lot, and the attack made parallel (reducing time), using techniques in Paul C. van Oorschot and Michael J. Wiener, [*Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications*](https://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/JoC97.pdf), in [Journal of Cryptology, 1999](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00003816). That would be a must for $b=128$ of AES.