# Exploit 3DES-CBC with known checksum of plaintext and repeated IV

Tags: cryptanalysis, cbc, 3des

I came across the following enterprise encryption scheme. I laughed when I first saw it, but I'm not a specialist and I'd like to know how bad it really is.

- 3DES-CBC
- k1=k2=k3 for 3DES
- IV for CBC is repeated every 256 messages. Every communication party has a different set of 256 IVs but they are all predictable and similar in many places. IV has a fixed part unique for each communication party and an 8-bit counter.
- 16bit checksum of plaintext is known (sum of all bytes modulo 2^16)
- plaintext of some messages or part of it is known but it is not obvious, which message contains it

I wonder if this information can be used to further weaken an already weak algorithm and if it opens doors for feasible brute-force attacks or any other more clever methods.

Comment: "k1=k2=k3" for 3DES means it's equivalent to simple-DES. thus [by design](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34228/555) the key can be found at low cost with FPGAs, and has been so for decades ([ref1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker), [ref2](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rnc1/descrack/DEScracker.html#SecFPGA), [ref3](https://www.copacobana.org), [ref4](https://crack.sh/)). How the IV and checksum can be exploited is heavily context-dependent. I'm not making this an answer because we lack details for these other attacks.

Comment: Given the description of the IV & checksum can at least be used to (mostly) validate a guessed single DES key. Given that this is DES, I don't think you'd need much more.

Comment: Thank you, guys. So, bruteforce is doable but probably still impractical in my case. It is definitely vulnerable to replay attacks. I was hoping for something similar to the Padding Oracle attack and an attack similar to BEAST. Are there any details I should provide?